# Make \includegraphics search \graphicspath before current directory

Tags: graphics, paths

I would like LaTeX, when I specify `\graphicspath` to browse these locations before looking for the file in the current directory.

A simple MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{subdir/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{pic.png}
\end{document}
```

When two different images `pic.png` are placed in the CWD and in subfolder `subdir`, the one in CWD is used, I would like the other one to be used.

You can use e.g. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Example.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjnHU.png as the two images.

I have TeXLive 2012 on Fedora, but this should make no difference in this case, since it's `graphicx` package that takes case of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\makeatletter

\def\input@path{{}}% for \input etc

\long\def \IfFileExists#1#2#3{%
%  \openin\@inputcheck#1 %
%  \ifeof\@inputcheck
    \ifx\input@path\@undefined
      \def\reserved@a{#3}%
    \else
      \def\reserved@a{\@iffileonpath{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
    \fi
%  \else
%    \closein\@inputcheck
%    \edef\@filef@und{#1 }%
%    \def\reserved@a{#2}%
%  \fi
  \reserved@a}
\makeatother
```

Would (If my recollection is correct) remove the initial trial of the given filename and always use the `\graphicspath` so you would have to add an empty path `{}` at the end if you wanted it to try that at all.

Comment: I was just getting there, parsing your code with `texdef`. I yet modified your code to make TeX search TEXINPUTS as the last option...

Comment: Is it normal that I keep getting `No file <filename>.aux` warning?

Comment: @karlkoeller Um I did what the question asked, but You'd also need a global `\def\input@path{{}}` so normal file handling looked in the normal place. I'll add

Comment: @David now it's great.

Comment: Great, this could be a new feature for a future release of the graphicx package.

Comment: @student it's not really related to the graphics packages (other than that they use the tex input path) , it is redefining how input path searching works in the latex format.